# Proving if a linear part of a function exists using algebra.(proof of the second derivative being zero at some point/points)

Tags: functions

I know that the following question can be resolved using derivatives but nonetheless, I would like to hear a more fluid and lucid approach. Any hand waving explanation and approximations are welcome.

The question is:-

> Prove that there exists a linear part of the function $f($x$)$ $=$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^3}}$ at x= $-1/2$ and x=$1/2$

Now initially I thought, we could use the binomial expression to expand the quantity, then I would find the quantity around the said $x$ values and pray to almighty that it would resemble a linear function. But could get nowhere. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: What is a "linear part" of a function?

Comment: @lulu I just meant a part of the graph behaves like a line

Comment: Do you just mean that the second derivative is $0$?  If so, I suggest editing your post to state that.

Comment: yes yes, but wont that motivate people to use calculus

Comment: nontheless i will do it

Comment: Looking quickly at functions of the form $F_n(x)=\frac 1{(1+x^2)^n}$ we see that they have inflection points at $\pm \frac 1{\sqrt{2n+1}}$.  That gives you want you want.  Of course, you still need to argue that the form is correct but maybe there's an easy way to see that.  The functional equation $F\left(\frac 1x\right)=x^{2n}F_n(x)$ might help.

Comment: @lulu how does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon=\pm1$.

$$\begin{align}f\left(\frac\varepsilon2+h\right)&=\left(\left(\frac\varepsilon2+h\right)^2+1\right)^{-3/2}\\
&=\left(\frac54+\varepsilon h+h^2\right)^{-3/2}\\
&=\left(\frac54\right)^{-3/2}\left(1+\frac{4\varepsilon}5h+\frac45h^2\right)^{-3/2}\\
&=\left(\frac54\right)^{-3/2}\left(1-\frac32\left(\frac{4\varepsilon}5h+\frac45h^2\right)+\frac{\left(-\frac32\right)\left(-\frac52\right)}2\left(\frac{4\varepsilon}5h\right)^2+o(h^2)\right)\\
&=\left(\frac54\right)^{-3/2}\left(1-\frac{6\varepsilon}5h+o(h^2)\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: what is ‘O’…………

Comment: I wrote $o$ (little o, defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)), not $O$ (big O). $o(h^2)$ means: $h^2e(h)$, where $e$ is a function such that $\lim_{h\to0}e(h)=0$.